# Sum up values of a multi dimensional array where some items in array are repeated

Tags: php, arrays

I'm drawing a blank here and need some help.  I have a multi-dimensional array and i need to combine the data from the same "tenant_id" item so I end up with one array with summed up "item_amounts" and concatenated descriptions for any tenant_id duplicates.

Here is my php array...notice the first 2 elements are from the same tenant_id, which I need to combine into one and add together the "item_amount" to get one final total:

```
/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11252"
    ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
    ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.00"
    ["description"]=>    string(4) "Rent"
    ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3073)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11252"
    ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
    ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.20"
    ["description"]=>    string(12) "Security dep"
    ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3074)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11175"
    ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
    ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.10"
    ["description"]=>    string(4) "Rent"
    ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3075)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11120"
    ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
    ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.00"
    ["description"]=>    string(1) "r"
    ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3076)
  }
}

*/
```

This is the end result I'm hoping for which has a summed up "invoice_amount" and a concatenated description for those "tenant_id" that are the same:

```
/*
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11252"
        ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
        ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "2.20"
        ["description"]=>    string(4) "Rent,Security dep"
        ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3073)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11175"
        ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
        ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.10"
        ["description"]=>    string(4) "Rent"
        ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3075)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
        ["tenant_id"]=>    string(5) "11120"
        ["payment_method_id"]=>    string(1) "4"
        ["item_amount"]=>    string(4) "1.00"
        ["description"]=>    string(1) "r"
        ["acctg_payment_id"]=>    int(3076)
      }
    }

    */
```

Any help on figuring out how to accomplish this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't do that. You're not only losing information, but the info that you leave in is misleading. eg: you consolidate multiple payments, but leave in one `acctg_payment_id`. I suggest something like:

```
[
    '11252' => [ //tenant ID
        'total_paid' => 220,
        'payments' => [
            [ /* payment 3073 */ ],
            [ /* payment 3074 */ ],
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

Which should be output by:

```
$res = [];
foreach($payments as $payment) {
    $tid = $payment['tenant_id'];
    if( !isset($res[$tid]) ) {
        $res[$tid] = [
            'total_paid' => $payment['item_amount'],
            'payments' => [$payment]
        ];
    } else {
        $res[$tid]['total_paid'] += $payment['item_amount'];
        $res[$tid]['payments'][] = $payment;
    }
}
```